# reading in a file and assigning values to a map

Tags: c++, file, parsing

I have to read in a file parsed at the commas.

file example:

```
  class Instructor {
      private:
          int Id;
          string name;
          string dept;
          string emailAddress;

      public:
          static Instructor findInstructor(int ID);
          static map<int,Instructor> instructorList;
          Instructor():Id(-1),name(""),dept(""),emailAddress(""){};
          Instructor(int ID, string name, string dept,string email):Id(ID),name(name),dept(dept),emailAddress(email){};
          static int loadInstructors();
          string getName() {return name;}
          int getId() {return Id;}
          string getDept() {return dept;}
          string getEmailAddress() {return emailAddress;}
          friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out,Instructor i)//overloading << operator
          {
              out<<i.name<<"("<<i.Id<<")";
              return out;
          }

  };
```

Here is the code I use to rad/parse the file.

```
 int Instructor::loadInstructors()
 {
     string comma;
     string line;
     ifstream myfile("instructor.dat");
     string name,email = "";
     string dept = "";
     int id;
     if (myfile.is_open())
     {
         while (getline(myfile,line))
         {
             //parse line
             string myText(line);
             istringstream iss(myText);
             if(!(iss>>id)) id=0;

             //parses the string into independent string variables
             iss.ignore(1,',');
             std::getline(iss,name,',');
             std::getline(iss,dept,',');
             std::getline(iss,email,',');
             Instructor newInstructor(id,name,dept,email);
             Instructor::instructorList.insert(std::pair<int,Instructor>(id,newInstructor));
         }
         myfile.close();
     }
     else
     {
         cout << "Unable to open file:" << endl;
         return -1;
     }

     return 0;
```

In the class I over the << operator to print in a specific format

```
cout<<i.name<<"("<<i.id<<")"<<endl;
```

The two constructors for the class are:

```
          Instructor():Id(-1),name(""),dept(""),emailAddress(""){};
          Instructor(int ID, string name, string dept,string email):Id(ID),name(name),dept(dept),emailAddress(email){};
```

When I run through the map and print off each instructor this is my output:
code:

```
     for (map<int,Instructor>::iterator it = Instructor::instructorList.begin();it!=Instructor::instructorList.end();++it)
     {
         Instructor instruct = it->second;
         std::cout<<(it->second)<<endl;
     }


(-1)
(-1)
(-1)
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I have another section of code that I identical but with different variable names and it works perfectly. When I copied that over and changed the variables it still doesn't work.

EDIT:
I expanded the file to read in by several more lines here is the output and file

```
  Instructor List
  (-1)
  (-1)
  Dr rmith(2)
  (-1)
  Dr all(4)
  Dr tll(5)
  Dr yll(6)
  Dr ull(7)
  Dr ill(8)
```

file:

```
  1 0,Dr all,Math,wall@eng.ua.edu
  2 4,Dr all,Math,wall@eng.ua.edu
  3 1,Dr Wall,Math,wall@eng.ua.edu
  4 2,Dr rmith,CS,smith@eng.ua.edu
  5 3,Dr all,Math,wall@eng.ua.edu
  6 4,Dr rll,Math,wall@eng.ua.edu
  7 5,Dr tll,Math,wall@eng.ua.edu
  8 6,Dr yll,Math,wall@eng.ua.edu
  9 7,Dr ull,Math,wall@eng.ua.edu
 10 8,Dr ill,Math,wall@eng.ua.edu
```

Comment: Do you have the assignment operator `=` overloaded?

Comment: @AndrewDunn no the only one overloaded is the << operator

Comment: in your Instructor constructor, naming your class variable and function argument is a pretty unsafe practice. I would recommend changing your arguments to differ from your class vars

Comment: @Gmercer015 As long used only in the initializer list these would be unambiguous for the compiler.

Comment: @user3341518 Forget about my answer, it was silly! Your code wouldn't have been compilable for such case. I'd recommend you to post your code as a minimal sample, that reproduces the problem (please without the line numbers then) and can be easily checked here from others with e.g. an online IDE.

Comment: what code would you be looking for?

Comment: I added in more code.